# How to write a nice function that passes variables by reference?

Tags: cmake

as in said in the title, I would like to write a "nice" function in cmake that is able to modify a variable which is passed as a parameter into that function.

The only way I can think of doing it is ugly:

*Function definition*

```
function(twice varValue varName)
set(${varName} ${varValue}${varValue} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction(twice)
```

*Usage*

```
set(arg foo)
twice(${arg} arg)
message("arg = "${arg})
```

*Result*

```
arg = foofoo
```

It seems to me, there is no real concept of variables that one can pass around at all?!
I feel like there is something fundamental about cmake that I didn't take in yet.

So, is there a nicer way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2017/blob/master/05-19-2017_friday/effective_cmake__daniel_pfeifer__cppnow_05-19-2017.pdf suggests that you use macros when you want to modify a parameter.

Comment: Your are correct, but it is not your fault. CMake is missing fundamental concepts of real scripting languages.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You don't need to pass the value and the name of the variable. The name is enough, because you can access the value by the name:

```
function(twice varName)
  SET(${varName} ${${varName}}${${varName}} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

SET(arg "foo")
twice(arg)
MESSAGE(STATUS ${arg})
```

outputs "foofoo"

Comment: thanks a lot, it's working. However, I noticed some strange behaviour, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397298/cmake-strange-function-argument-name-behaviour)

Answer (score 9):

I use these two macros for debugging:

```
macro(debug msg)
    message(STATUS "DEBUG ${msg}")
endmacro()

macro(debugValue variableName)
    debug("${variableName}=\${${variableName}}")
endmacro()
```

Usage:

```
set(MyFoo "MyFoo's value")
debugValue(MyFoo)
```

Output:

```
MyFoo=MyFoo's value
```