# How to modify an existing variable?

Tags: cmake

I want to modify a variable passed to a function. Here's the code I wrote:

```
FUNCTION(TEST var)
    set(${var} "ABC")
    message(${var}) # 2) 123
    set(${var} "ABC" PARENT_SCOPE)
ENDFUNCTION(TEST)

set(v "123")
message(${v}) # 1) 123
TEST(${v})
message(${v}) # 3) 123
```

Why all three outputs print `123`. I expected `#2` and `#3` print `ABC`?

If I pass variable like this - `TEST(v)` - I have other output: `#1 - 123`, `#2 - v`, `#3 - ABC`. Why is this? What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the content of `v` to `TEST()`. So it should be:

```
FUNCTION(TEST var)
    set(${var} "ABC")
    message(${${var}})
    set(${var} "ABC" PARENT_SCOPE)
ENDFUNCTION(TEST)

set(v "123")
message(${v}) 
TEST(v)
message(${v})
```

**Reference**

- [cmake - How to write a nice function that passes variables by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375519/cmake-how-to-write-a-nice-function-that-passes-variables-by-reference)
- [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)

Comment: Thank you. This works for a "normal" variable but doesn't work for a list variable. And what's this '${${var}}`? Why we need double braces here?

Comment: @nikitablack That also works for list variables since lists in CMake are only semicolon separated strings. And the double braces are needed for double dereferencing (first the name of the variable, then content of this variable)